# Saving a base64 image to a MySQL blob field with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base64, blob

I have this customer that saves files as base64 into a MEDIUMBLOB field (please don't ask why).

The files is saved like this:

```
$file      = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$file      = base64_encode($file);
$file      = mysql_real_escape_string($file);
$file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_ext  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['type']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO $file_table_name (file, file_name, file_ext) VALUES ('$file', '$file_name', '$file_ext')";
```

This is the code I'm using to force download the file:

```
header('Content-type: ' . $data->file_ext);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $data->file_name . '"');
echo base64_decode($data->file);
die();
```

For some reason, this works fine with PDF files, but not image files. When I try to open the file in Windows Preview it says: "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is too large". The original file is ~150KB.

If I do this;

```
echo '<img src="data:' . $data->file_ext . ';base64,'.$data->file.'" />';
die();
```

...the image looks fine and I'm able to save the image (save as) without issues.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Am I missing any headers?

**Update with values from the DB:**

**file_name:** 'test.png'
**file_ext:** 'image/png'
**file:** https://gist.githubusercontent.com/horgen/25298f2689d9aed865db/raw/gistfile1.txt
**The original file:** http://cl.ly/image/2o3X3u3a0V0S
**The encoded file:** http://cl.ly/image/1S3K3v0x0U0p

Comment: I just tried your code with the example values (encoded file) and there doesn't seem to be any problem. I can run the script fine, the file downloads and I can open the image in Windows Photo Viewer (Win 7) and Irfanview without any errors. Maybe you have some error when reading the data from database or maybe some images are corrupted in the database?

Comment: Basicly I just did this: `header('Content-type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.png"');
    echo base64_decode('iVBORw...long string of base64 data...SuQmCC');
    die();`

Answer (score 1):

Try using readfile(base64_decode($data->file)) instead of echo.

Comment: `readfile()` will try to read a file from the filesystem and output that file which isn't what is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
echo base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $data->file));
```

See the PHP manual page for [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) and also the comments on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. This is akward.. I found the problem. This is a Wordpress site and I have this functions.php file where I include all my functions. For some reason the previous developer on this project included a php file inside functions.php. The included file had some whitespace/tab before the "php"-tag and this generated a newline in the decoded file :S

Anyways, thank you all for trying to help me :)